# Increase Grails/Tomcat active HTTP connection limit

Tags: spring, tomcat, grails, connection, limit

I am developing an AJAX application that utilizes a connection that is kept-alive until an event occurs. For each window, a HTTP connection will be open at all times listening for events from the server. On the server side, the thread dealing with the request will simply be frozen until it is thaw by another event. While being frozen, the monitor threads are disconnected from the database.

The number of active connections seems to be limited at about 6. How can I increase this? Do the HTTP request header or whether I use GET or POST have any effect on the limit?

Comment: Actually, the connection limit in this case comes from the browser (Chrome not allowing more than 6 simultaneous connections to the same host. I wonder how Google Docs is able to keep more connections than that. I will investigate on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @fabus mentioned, the restriction is in your browser. You can only have so many open connections to a particular address. Google overcomes the problem in their apps by hosting the imagery on multiple different servers with different names. If you go to Google Maps and watch the status bar, you'll see "Loading from..." messages flashing by with different host names. Once you overcome that, however, you still have to consider the server-side impact. It's pretty well agreed, I think, that a few thousand threads is about the max you should expect from a JVM. You might want to look into an non-blocking implementation if you really want to hold long-lived persistent connections open.

Comment: Thanks a lot, are you talking about the APR and NIO non-blocking implementations? Can you point me at a good tutorial how to work with persistent connections utilizing these implementations?

Comment: Yes, I believe APR and NIO are the Tomcat options for doing this. Unfortunately, I don't know any good resources, as I've never really had to get into it. If you're looking at doing Comet, you should consider that a common "implementation" of Comet is to have clients poll the server instead of having a persistent connection open. I know it's not exactly pure "server push", but it does nicely work around the problems with persistent connections.